# Night Vision Camera Android Application

Tags: android, camera, settings

Am looking to make Night Vision Camera Android Application, some says there is no such inbuilt features in Android, Some its just adjusting camera effect,

I need a clear clarification, is that possible to make night vision camera application for Android, or all existing night vision apps are just doing camera tricks?

Kindly help me

Answer (score 6):

The camera of androids devices don't allow you to do what you want. But there is a camera named "Therm-App" that transforms Android smartphones into thermal cameras.

On their [website](http://therm-app.com/#), they say that a SDK is available.

"Through our SDK, we let the crowd decide which Therm-App™ applications will be produced, changing our everyday life and making sure there’s always more to see!"

Most of all existing night vision apps need light. Then it increases the light to give the illusion of a thermal camera.

Comment: this website sells external thermal camera with sdk, it's not just sdk